# Constrain ARIMA to positive values (Python)

Tags: forecasting, python, arima

I am working on a time series whose values are strictly positive. However, in some cases when the values are near zero, the forecast also takes negative values.

Is there a way to tell to the Python statsmodel package to stay positive?

Example of the code I am using now:

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order = pdq,
                                seasonal_order = seasonal_pdq,
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)
results = mod.fit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classical way [to ensure that forecasts stay positive](https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html) is to take logarithms of the original series, model these, forecast, and transform back. This is a specific case of the more general Box-Cox transform.

Be aware that you can't just backtransform by taking exponentials, since this will introduce a bias - the exponentiated forecasts will be too low. [You need to adjust the backtransformation using the residual variance.](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html)

Alternatively, you can of course always truncate forecasts from below.