# How can I ensure that my backcasting values are positive in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Is there any option in R that could allow me to obtain just positive values in my forecast? I applied the following code for backcasting public expenditure in health quarterly time-series, but I obtained some negative values:

```
He.ts <-ts (GP1$He,st=2008,freq=4)
x <- He.ts
h <- 32
f <- frequency(x)
revx <- ts(rev(x), frequency = f)
fc <- forecast(auto.arima(revx), h)
```

To be added, the data I have available for my study is the public expenditure in health from the first quarter of 2008 to the last quarter of 2018. However, I need to have information of this variable since 2000, therefore I'm trying to backcast the quarterly values from 2000 to 2007.

Comment: I assume that the `frequency = f` in your definition of `revx` should be a `4` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The classical way [to ensure that forecasts stay positive](https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html) is to take logarithms of the original series, model these, forecast, and transform back. This is a specific case of the more general Box-Cox transform.

Be aware that you can't just backtransform by taking exponentials, since this will introduce a bias - the exponentiated forecasts will be too low. [You need to adjust the backtransformation using the residual variance.](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html)

If you use `forecast::auto.arima()`, you can force it to use a specific Box-Cox transformation by specifying the `lambda` parameter. For the log transform, use `lambda=0`. This should ensure that `forecast()` also does the correct bias adjustment back-transform.

Alternatively, you can of course always truncate forecasts from below.

*This is taken verbatim from [an earlier answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/388874/1352), which is not an exact duplicate, since this one explicitly asks about R.*

Comment: +1: Thank you for this great answer. Exponentiation will clearly give us a positive value, but can you explain the residual variance adjustment a bit and why we can be certain that this adjustment will not take any of our forecasts into negative territory. In forecasting series for which it makes less sense to take the logarithm, such as interest rates, the question remains as to how to ensure the forecasts stay positive. Or would you still take the log of an interest rate (one that cannot go negative) to ensure a positive forecast?

Comment: @ColorStatistics: the idea always is to take the original time series, transform it, model the transformed data, forecast out, then back-transform the forecasts. The key aspect is that the forecasts usually aim at the expected value of the conditional distribution, but the trivial back-transformation does not commute with taking the expectation: $E(f(X))\neq f(EX)$. Simplest example: if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $EX=\mu$, but $E(e^X)\neq e^\mu$, but $E(e^X)=e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$ - see Wikipedia on the lognormal distribution. ...

Comment: ... The multiplication by $e^\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$ is the necessary bias correction. And note that we are *multiplying* by a positive quantity, so we will not end up with a negative result. Analogous formulas are used for other Box-Cox transformations than the log one, see the link to FPP2 for details.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification